# How to save a new data row

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

How to save the data after applying data in the column using pgadmin's interfac pgadmin without using any sql code?

I cannot find a function or similiar to save the data after adding a new row.

You are enable to do it in SQL server.

Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Right-click on your table, select View/Edit Data -> All Row
2. add/edit your data
3. after adding/ editing your rows in PgAdmin , press `F6` to save your changes